# Item in a dictionary

Tags: vba

Following is the code to read the number of keys in every dictionary whose object acts as the item in the main dictionary (`channel`).

```
Dim facebook As Object, instagram As Object, twitter As Object, name As String, channel As Object, _
type_name As String, Key As Variant, values(5) As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

Set facebook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 0 To 4
    values(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1)
Next i

With facebook
    .Add "brand", values
    .Add "post", 6
    .Add "likes", 7
End With

Set instagram = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With instagram
    .Add "brand", 8
    .Add "post", 9
    .Add "likes", 10
End With

Set twitter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With twitter
    .Add "brand", 11
    .Add "post", 12
    .Add "likes", 13
End With

Set channel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With channel
    .Add "facebook", facebook
    .Add "twitter", twitter
    .Add "instagram", instagram
End With

For i = 0 To channel.count - 1
    MsgBox channel.Keys(i) & " has " & channel(channel.Keys(i)).count & " keys."
Next i
```

Error which is occurring is shown in the given image file:

[image: Error]

If I replace `MsgBox channel.Keys(i) & " has " & channel(channel.Keys(i)).count & " keys."` with `MsgBox channel.Keys(i) & " has " & channel.Items(i).count & " keys."`, then also it is giving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary.Keys()` is not a property, it's a function and it does not accept parameters. It always returns all keys, and you need to pick the one you need *after* it returns:

```
MsgBox channel.Keys()(i) & " has " & channel(channel.Keys()(i)).Count & " keys."
```